# How did Ross Chastain's 'wallride' allow him to pass his opponents?

Tags: forces, centripetal-force

There's a clip going around on the internet of the driver Ross Chastain, 'wall riding' in a race that allowed him to pass many opponents on one turn. [Here is the clip.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KNGN_mLyCpo&ab_channel=Tuned2.7) What I do not understand is how did this work? The only explanation I can think of is that the normal force of the wall acted like a centripetal force, which meant he didn't have to brake on the turn, but this doesn't make too much sense to me since the frictional force of the wall on the car would slow him down quite a lot.

Comment: It looks to me that it's not so much the impact of the wall that allowed him to pass many opponents as the fact that the rest of the racers were on the inside and he ran the outside. But I'm not much of a nascar fan, so I don't know much.

Comment: @KyleKanos Im not a nascar fan either, but I believe running the outside line should be slower actually since its a physically longer distance.

Comment: I think your explanation is right. But friction did not slow him as much as you are thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also not a nascar fan, so I will not pretend to know more about this incident from what is simple to analyse from Newtonian mechanics.

We will need to cover both the friction from the ground and friction from the wall, so we need to denote them by $\mu_g$ and $\mu_w$ respectively. Note that $\mu_g$ is a static friction coefficient, whereas $\mu_w$ is a kinetic friction coefficient.

You already correctly noted that we have to consider centripetal acceleration. The friction force on the ground on the cars, should be approximate-able to have no change in speed, since they are all trying to rush as quickly as they can. They are pros, they ought to know what are the maximum turning speeds their cars can go at without dangerous slipping. The formula for centripetal acceleration, and by extension, the magnitude of the force giving the centripetal acceleration, is usually remembered in the linear velocity form. But actually, it is better to inspect the angular velocity form here:
$$\tag1\text{N2L}:\quad\sum\vec F=\frac{\mathrm d\vec p}{\mathrm dt}=m\vec a\quad\implies\quad f_g=m\frac{v^2}r\quad\bigwedge\quad v=r\omega\quad\implies\quad  f_g=mr\omega^2$$
Now, the cars are all similarly sized, with similar masses and all, $f_g\leqslant \mu_gmg$ will be almost at this maximum, since they are all trying to skirt around the fastest they can go. This means that for the same $f_g$, a smaller $r$ is better for turning around at a faster $\omega$, hence why their conventional wisdom is to have every car pile up at the innermost lane.

Actually, the friction from the ground would have to also provide some forward thrust to balance the air resistance, which would not have been negligible at their speeds, but for a first consideration, we can ignore this for now.

Now, consider the wall scraping case. In this case, the friction on the ground can focus upon forward thrust, i.e. he can floor the accelerator much more than his peers. The lane is very open too. The wall is the one providing centripetal acceleration. Basically it can give unlimited force for this purpose, so we are really balancing the forward thrust friction from the ground, with the wall scraping friction dragging it back. i.e.
\begin{align}
\tag2\leftarrow+\text{ve}:\qquad f_g-\mu_wN&=0\\
\tag3\mu_gmg=\mu_wN&=\mu_wmR\Omega^2\\
\tag4\frac{\mu_g}{\mu_w}g&=R\Omega^2\\
\tag5\frac{r\omega^2}{\mu_w}&=R\Omega^2\\
\tag6\frac1{\mu_w}\frac rR&=\left(\frac\Omega\omega\right)^2
\end{align}
Now, as long as $0<\mu_w<\frac rR<1$, then $\Omega>\omega$ and we have a net win.

If the wall or the car is angled so that this wall scraping pushes the car downwards, then this increases the maximum friction = forward thrust that ground can provide to the car, and it will then give an even greater boost.

Needless to say, this is a sneaky move that will only work if the finish line is incredibly near to, or is in the middle of, a turn, and only if he is doing it in the last lap, so that nobody else is copying his trick.

Answer (score 0):

> The only explanation I can think of is that the normal force of the wall acted like a centripetal force, which meant he didn't have to brake on the turn

That's correct.  You can take the *like* out of that sentence.  It was indeed the centripetal force for the turn (minus a tiny amount from banking)

> but this doesn't make too much sense to me since the frictional force of the wall on the car would slow him down quite a lot.

Certainly there is some friction so he wasn't going as fast as a car would in a straight line.  But it wasn't so much as to take away the advantage it gave.

This race was on a smaller track with very short radius turns.   There is 11 degrees of banking to assist, but that's insufficient for the cars to make high-speed turns with just the friction of the tires on the road.  Cars must slow down significantly on the turns to keep in line.

The flat wall would have produced some friction, but but the normal force from it allowed a *significantly* higher speed car to negotiate the turn.